# Is it possible to charge additional amount in running billing cycle in paypal pro?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I am working on one website where i need to add additional charge on the running billing cycle of the user.

Like on start phase i will charge user to 169.99$ per month using paypal pro createrecurringprofile method, but on next month if user required some other things from my website then i need to charge 50$ extra for that particular month.

So is it possible to do something like that, where i can charge user for particular month and the next billing cycle will work like as it on regular phase.

Also is it possible to add discount amount in running billing cycle and for the next month it will work like as it is?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not enough specific for SO. Please see [ask]